# Concatenar la columna del archivo b.txt al archivo a.txt cuando los datos sean iguales

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, awk

Contenido de archivo a.txt

```
1
2
3
_____
4
5
6
_____
7
8
9
```

Contenido de archivo b.txt:

```
2
4
6
8
```

Resultado deseado:

```
2       2
____
4      4
6      6
_____
8      8
```

He intentado con:

```
$ awk '{var=$1;next}{if($var == $1)printf $var ,$1}' a.txt b.txt >resultado.txt
```

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' he intentado con awk pero no muestra nada               awk '{var=$1;next}{if($var == $1)printf  $var ,$1}' a.txt b.txt >resultado.txt

Comment: @Bennacer, modifiqué el formato de tu pregunta para que sea más accesible para poder recibir ayuda.

Comment: @Bennacer. Estoy tratando de contestar tu respuesta, pero de todas maneras, no entiendo porqué tu resultado imprime la línea si precisamente no concuerda con lo que planteas, es decir, que se encuentre en ambos archivos. Justamente la línea sólo se encuentra en uno de ellos

Comment: Sería bueno Bennacer que detallaras la lógica. ¿Son realmente números solamente o hay algún otro tipo de caracteres? ¿Es solamente un campo o la línea consiste en más cosas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {pass1 = 1; pass2 = 0}
      pass1 { afile1[FNR]+=$0 }
      NR != 1 && FNR == 1 { pass1=0; pass2 = 1 }
      pass2 { afile2[FNR]+=$0 }
      END{ for (key1 in afile1)
              for (key2 in afile2)
              if (afile1[key1] == afile2[key2])
              print afile1[key1] "  " afile2[key2]
      }' a.txt b.txt
```

Que arrojará esto:

```
2  2
4  4
6  6
8  8
```

La verdad lo hice sin pensarle mucho, fue más automático, por lo que la explicación que te pueda dar no será muy clara. Lo que si te puedo decir es que:

- `awk` utiliza la sintaxis `patrón{acción}`
- El patrón `BEGIN` ejecuta la acción antes de que se lean los registros: ahí inicializamos `pass1 = 1` (para inicializar el flag de lectura primer archivo) y dejar en claro al lector del código (porque en realidad no se necesita) que se bloquea la lectura al siguiente archivo con `pass2 = 0`
- cuando el patrón pass1 es diferente de 0 (osea que `awk` puede leer el primer archivo), el registro entero (mostrado por la variable $0) se almacena en el array `afile1` usando el valor de la variable interna `FNR` (el número de rengistro del **archivo en curso**) como clave
- Cuando la variable interna `NR` es diferente de 1 y la variable `FNR` es igual a 1 (osea que estamos al inicio del siguiente archivo pero no es el incio de la lectura), se cambian las flags para que: 1) bloqueé el almacenamiento del archivo en el array `afile1`, 2) pero permita el almacenamiento del siguiente archivo en el array `afile2`
- Con el patrón `END`, al final de que todos los registros han sido consumidos, comparamos  el contenido de cada renglón del primer archivo con el contenido del relglón del segundo

De hecho creo que se puede resumir todavía más:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {pass1 = 1; pass2 = 0}
      pass1 { afile1[FNR]+=$0 }
      NR != 1 && FNR == 1 { pass1 = 0; pass2 = 1 }
      pass2 { 
        for (key1 in afile1)
          if ($0 == afile1[FNR])
            print afile1[key1] "  " $0
      }' a.txt b.txt
```

Y el resultado es el mismo.

Siento que hay una manera de hacerlo más sencilla y general de hacerlo (para múltiples archivos) pero no la puedo ofrecer en este momento. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muy rebuscado lo veo. ¿Y parsear primero b y luego a? `awk 'NR==FNR {items[$0];next} ($1 in items) {print $1,$1}'`. Nótese por cierto que definir en BEGIN un valor como 0 es innecesario, ya valen así por defecto.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Si, yo también le vi algo raro. En un momento lo reviso. Por cierto, lo de BEGIN que mencionas es cierto, sin embargo, como expliqué e mi respuesta: es únicamente para dejarle claro al lector que hay un segundo archivo.

Comment: Puedes jugar con el hecho de que FNR==NR cuando lees el primer fichero, así como usar BEGINFILE de GNU Awk